# linq any clause on multiple values

Tags: linq

I am trying to create a linq statement to filter otu results using an any clause.  My issue is that I dont have a single value to compare against.

In the example below I have a PropertyTaxBill entity that is the parent.  Each one has a collection of TaxPropertyAssessmentDetails attached to it.

In this query people can specify that they only want to deal with bills pertaining to a specific class strata so I check to see if any values exist in the classStrata variable.  If so then the user selected specific ones.  I was trying to do an any clause on the classStrata but instead of giving it a single value to match on I was trying to select all the values in the TaxPropertyAssessmentDetails collection attached to the PropertyTaxBill.  Is this possible?

```
using (var dataContext = contextProvider.GetContext())
{

    var query = dataContext.PropertyTaxBills.Where(x => x.Id > 1);
    var classStrata = new int[0];

    if (classStrata != null && classStrata.Any())
    {
        query = query.Where(x => classStrata.Any(y => y == x.TaxPropertyAssessmentDetails.SelectMany(z => z.PropertyTaxClassStrataId)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't quite picture what I would need for a predicate to handle this situation within the any.  Could you post an example?

Comment: `x => classStrata.Any(y => x.TaxPropertyAssessmentDetails.Any(z => z.PropertyTaxClassStrataId == y))`. Or even better `x => x.TaxPropertyAssessmentDetails.Any(z => classStracta.Contains(z.PropertyTaxClassStrataId))`

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use contains so that ef is able to translate to a ef query.
Not sure that i understood your model correctly. Here's a example with a model. Please tell me if i understood incorrect so i can fix it.

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    IEnumerable<TaxBill> TaxBills = new List<TaxBill>();

    var query = TaxBills.Where(x => x.Id > 1);
    var classStrata = new int[0];

    if (classStrata != null && classStrata.Any())
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.AssessmentDetails.Any(ad => ad.TaxClassStrataId.Any(cs => classStrata.Contains(cs))));
    }
}
```

And the entities

```
public class TaxBill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AsessmentDetails> AssessmentDetails { get; set; }
}
public class AsessmentDetails
{
    public ICollection<int> TaxClassStrataId { get; set; }
}
```